# Top position for Kendo chart series item label

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I have Kendo column chart with multiple series per category.

I'm trying to put Kendo chart series item labels on top regardless of value. By default, it's put in the end of chart item. So for positive values it's on top of column and for negatives it's at the bottom.

[image: Overlapping label and note]

`app.component.html`

```html
<kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [labels]="{ margin: { top: 10 } }">
    </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-category-axis>

  <kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-value-axis>

  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let groupedResult of groupedData"
                            [data]="groupedResult.items"
                            field="income"
                            type="column"
                            categoryField="clientName"
                            noteTextField="income">
      <kendo-chart-series-item-labels format="C0">
      </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
      <kendo-chart-series-item-notes position="bottom"
                                     [icon]="{ visible: false }"
                                     [line]="{ width: 0 }"
                                     [label]="noteLabel">
      </kendo-chart-series-item-notes>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

`app.component.ts`

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export type TrendItem = {
  clientName: string;
  year: number;
  period: number;
  income: number;
};

export type GroupedTrendItem = {
  value: { year: number; period: number };
  items: TrendItem[];
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public trendItems: TrendItem[] = [
    {
      clientName: 'Client1',
      year: 2020,
      period: 3,
      income: -35,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client1',
      year: 2020,
      period: 4,
      income: 40,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      year: 2020,
      period: 1,
      income: -15,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      year: 2020,
      period: 2,
      income: 20,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      year: 2020,
      period: 3,
      income: 15,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client3',
      year: 2020,
      period: 2,
      income: 50,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client3',
      year: 2020,
      period: 3,
      income: -35,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client3',
      year: 2020,
      period: 4,
      income: 20,
    },
  ];

  public noteLabel = {
    color: 'black',
    content: e => `Q${e.dataItem.period} ${e.dataItem.year}`,
    font: '12px Arial',
    margin: -30,
  };

  private getGroupedTrends() {
    const groupedTrendItems = this.trendItems.reduce((acc, trendItem) => {
      let element = acc.find(el => el.value.year === trendItem.year
        && el.value.period === trendItem.period
      );

      if (element) {
        element.items.push(trendItem);
      } else {
        acc.push({
          value: { year: trendItem.year, period: trendItem.period },
          items: [trendItem],
        });
      }
      return acc;
    }, [] as GroupedTrendItem[]);

    return _.sortBy(groupedTrendItems, [
      item => item.value.year,
      item => item.value.period,
    ]);
  }

  public groupedData = this.getGroupedTrends();

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.groupedData);
  }
}
```

You can try this code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsczmx-qra7y7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Unfortunately, labels don't have available 'top' option for [`SeriesLabelsPosition`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesLabelsPosition/) component when working with column chart (TBH I don't know why).
If I don't need to display period, I will be using [`SeriesNotesComponent`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesNotesComponent/) like I do now for periods. They can have `position="top"` assigned without any problem.

---

So, the question is how to get labels displayed on top of column regardless of value.

Comment: There is a `position` attribute for the `kendo-chart-series-item-labels` element. You can see the possible values [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesLabelsPosition/). See if maybe `position="insideEnd"` is good enough for you. Unfortunately, no option to always show on top as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you want me to add the above comment as an answer or is it not relevant?

Comment: @Shai It's actually the question. I stated that available options of "position" doesn't work for me as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```html
<kendo-chart-series-item-labels format="C0" position="top" [margin]="-25">
</kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsczmx-swsaon?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

SeriesNoteLabel supports "new line" you can merge period and cost; I have prepared [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsczmx-nws25x) example for you.

```
content: e => `Q${e.dataItem.period} ${e.dataItem.year} \n ${this.currencyPipe.transform(e.dataItem.income)}`,
```

Comment: I want to see them at different levels: income above and period name below.